# mysql count query not adding up

Tags: mysql

Something strange is happening and I can't figure it out.

```
select DISTINCT locations.city,
       COUNT(*)
  from concerts,venues,locations,artists,users,user_concerts
 where concerts.artists = artists.id
   and concerts.venue_id = venues.id
   and venues.location_id = locations.id
   and (concerts.date between '1985-00-00' and '2021-06-24')
   AND concerts.id = user_concerts.concertid
   AND user_concerts.userid = 1
 GROUP BY locations.city
```

No idea where 15 comes from?  15 should equal 1?

```
city    COUNT(*)    
Charlottetown   15  
Chicago 15  
Edmonton    15  
Fredericton 15  
Halifax 105 
Milwaukee   15  
Minneapolis 15  
Moncton 30  
New York    15  
Ottawa  15  
Toronto 15  
Winnipeg    30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should opt for new join syntax instead of old ANSI-92 join syntax. So your query can be converted to -

```
SELECT locations.city,                 -- No need to use Distinct as we are grouping this column.
       COUNT(*)
  FROM concerts C
  JOIN venues V ON C.venue_id = V.id
  JOIN locations L ON V.location_id = L.id,artists
  JOIN users U ON ???                  -- You are missing a join condition for user table.
  JOIN user_concerts UC ON C.id = UC.concertid
 WHERE C.date BETWEEN '1985-00-00' AND '2021-06-24'
   AND UC.userid = 1
 GROUP BY locations.city
```

Please update your join condition of the User table and you should be good to go.